# How do I separate environments using `main` module approach in terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm following this `main` module approach to separate environments (where each environment is in it's own folder and using `main` module from root folder) (https://dev.to/piotrgwiazda/main-module-approach-for-handling-multiple-environments-in-terraform-1oln) but having hard time understanding how this shall work with shared components between environments? Example being a VNET.
I have exact structure listed in document and getting issues when trying to apply second environment after first one was already applied. Shared resources are not TF state for second environment and hence trying to be recreated.
How one can have 2 separate environments with this approach and yet have shared resources?
Here is my environment [image] which I apply with `terraform -chdir="./clients/client1" apply` and below is part of `main.tf` and `client1.tf` module which is just deploying all resources.

`client1.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.32.0"
    }
    tfe = {
      source  = "hashicorp/tfe"
      version = ">=0.43.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "utility-rg"
    storage_account_name = "XXXXXX"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.client1.tfstate"
  }
}



provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

}
module "main" {
  source            = "../../main"
  client_name       = "client1"
  app_subnet_prefix = "10.11.1.0/24"
  location          = "eastus"
}
```

`main.tf1`

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = var.client_name
  location = var.location
}


module "application" {
  source                                         = "../modules/app-service"
  resource_group                                 = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  client_name                                    = var.client_name
  location                                       = var.location
  service_plan_id                                = module.shared.app_service_plan_id
  database_url                                   = module.database.database_url
  database_username                              = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${module.key-vault.vault_uri}secrets/database-username)"
  database_password                              = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${module.key-vault.vault_uri}secrets/database-password)"
  azure_application_insights_instrumentation_key = module.application-insights.azure_application_insights_instrumentation_key
  vault_id                                       = module.key-vault.vault_id
  azure_storage_account_name                     = module.storage-blob.azurerm_storage_account_name
  azure_storage_blob_endpoint                    = module.storage-blob.azurerm_storage_blob_endpoint
  azure_storage_account_key                      = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${module.key-vault.vault_uri}secrets/storage-account-key)"
  subnet_id                                      = module.network.app_subnet_id
}

module "utilty" {
  source   = "../modules/utility"
  location = var.location
  rg_name  = "utility-rg"

}
```

Problem is with resources which needs to be shared between environments which live in `shared` folder. I assumed based on this statements ([https://dev.to/piotrgwiazda/main-module-approach-for-handling-multiple-environments-in-terraform-1oln#:~:text=Any%20shared%20remote%20resources%20will%20be%20included%20here.](https://dev.to/piotrgwiazda/main-module-approach-for-handling-multiple-environments-in-terraform-1oln#:%7E:text=Any%20shared%20remote%20resources%20will%20be%20included%20here.)) that I can add some modules somehow which will be shared between environments and still work.

Comment: Can you share your code? Because it's really hard to tell. One way could be to define outputs on a module level, the other could be to use data sources.

Comment: Updated with code example and folder structure. I assume I shall be deploying shared resources separately from environmental resources and use `data` to get hold of them but not sure what original author meant in his statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How one can have 2 separate environments with this approach and yet have shared resources?

You can't do that in one go. You have to do it in **two stages**.

1. Using TF, deploy all the shared resources, and output their IDs.
2. Second, pass the IDs of those resources as input arguments to the two TF code bases responsible for the two environments.

You can use **data sources** in the environments code to query the details of the shared resources.

Comment: Will this still work if those environments would need to modify shared resources (example adding subnets to VNET), since VNET is shared it would mean they modify shared resource and shared resource as a result will have inconsistent state?